# Resizing Images to have the same Height with CSS

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm trying to resize my images to have all the same height but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I tried adding min-height, max-height, having a fixed height(not my goal) but still can't figure out what is wrong. See how the middle flag is shorter than the rest. Also, how can I have the top of the flags image have the round corner? Right now they are hiding the border because they are on top.

[image]

Here is my code

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="content">
      <div
        class="country_card"
        v-for="country in countries"
        :key="country.name"
        @click="goToPage(`${country.name}`)"
      >
        <div class="country_flag">
          <img v-bind:src="country.flag" alt="Flag" />
        </div>
        <div class="country_info">
          <h3>{{country.name}}</h3>
          <div>
            <h5>
              <span>Population:</span>
              {{country.population.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")}}
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      countries: null,
    };
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then(response => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.countries = response.data;
    });
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.content {
  padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 75px;
}

.country_card {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.country_flag {
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

.country_info {
  padding: 20px 10px 20px 20px;
  h5 {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    &:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
  }
  span {
    font-weight: 800;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: How do you want the resizing to be done? Cropping or stretching?

Comment: Doesn't matter since some are shorter and some are bigger. As long as they all the same size.

Comment: Some flags will be cut out, is that OK?

Answer (score 0):

That's because images are inline elements, so first thing would be to display them block.

```
img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px; //whatever you want
}
```

Now you can style it as you want. As for the rounded corners, you just need to hide the overflow

Comment: I didn't want to add a fixed height, is there any other option?